# Create a map from class member type to class type in typescript generic function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the bellow function

```
export async function batchEntitiesBy<Entity, T extends keyof Entity>(
  entityClass: EntityTarget<Entity>
  by: T,
  variables: readonly Entity[T][]
) {
    by: T,
  variables: readonly Entity[T][]
) {
  // get entities from database ungrouped and in random order
  const entities = await db.find(entityClass, { [by]: In(variables as Entity[T][]) })

  // group the entities and order the groups by variables order
  type EntityMap = { [key in Entity[T]]: Entity[]}

  const entityMap = {} as EM;
  entities.forEach((e) => {
    if (!entityMap[e[by]]) {
      entityMap[e[by]] = []
    }
    entityMap[e[by]].push(e)
  })
  return variables.map((v) => entityMap[v]);
}
```

I would expect `Entity[T]` to give me the type of the class member specified in `by` and therefore `entityMap` to be a mapping from type(by) to type(Entity)

why am I getting this error??

```
Type 'Entity[T]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
  Type 'Entity[keyof Entity]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
    Type 'Entity[string] | Entity[number] | Entity[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
      Type 'Entity[string]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'.
```

---

Edit:

If I have an example entity

```
class ExampleEntity {
  a: string,
  b: number
}
```

I would expect

- `by` to be either `a` or `b`
- If `by` is `a` I would expect
  `Entity[T]` to be `string`

based on the typescript documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types

Here illustrating the same problem in [playgroud](https://tsplay.dev/wXqykN)

---

Edit2:

Some example entities I would like to use with this function:

```
class User {
  id: string
  name: string
  address: Address
  addressId: number
}

class Address {
  id: number
  street: string
  num: number
}
```

example usage:

```
const adrIds = [1,5,2,9,4]

const users = batchEntitiesBy<User, addressId>(Users, "addressId", adrIds)
```

Comment: `Entity[T]` cannot be used as a key. Did you mean to use `T`?

Comment: I added my assumptions above - does this not work?

Comment: TS doesn't know that `Entity[T]` always maps to a valid key.

Comment: But based on my code it should right? Can I override this somehow? Or is there a way to code it in a way that it makes sense for typescript?

Comment: Show us more precise what the issue is.
You can start from here: https://tsplay.dev/WGAX2N

Comment: @SvetoslavPetkov I have made a more complete example in the link you shared does this help?
https://tsplay.dev/wgQKvm

Comment: I have updated the playground example here https://tsplay.dev/wXqykN

Comment: @caTS any idea how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the developments based of the updated question and the discussion in chat, an additional difficulty was that the original code was using the values of `Entity` as keys in an object (`EntityMap`), but not every value of `Entity` was a valid key (namely `Address`). Using a `Map` instead of an object was one way to solve the problem.

---

I think the problem with your code is that you hesitate between using the generic `Entity` and `ExampleEntity`.

In the code bellow I used `ExampleEntity` throughout:

```js
type ExampleEntity = {
    a: string,
    b: number
}

const batchExampleEntitiesBy = async <By extends keyof ExampleEntity>(
    by: By, variables: readonly ExampleEntity[By][]
) => {
    const entityMap = {} as { [key in ExampleEntity[By]]: ExampleEntity[] }

    const entities = [
        { a: 'hello', b: 1 },
        { a: 'world', b: 2 },
        { a: 'hello', b: 3 },
        { a: 'world', b: 4 },
    ] as ExampleEntity[];

    entities.forEach((e) => {
        if (!entityMap[e[by]]) {
            entityMap[e[by]] = []
        }
        entityMap[e[by]].push(e)
    })

    return variables.map((v) => entityMap[v]);
};


const foo = batchExampleEntitiesBy("a", ["hello"])
```

In the code bellow I parameterised `ExampleEntity`:

```js
type ExampleEntity = {
    a: string,
    b: number
}

type Key = string | number | symbol;

const batchEntitiesBy = <Entity extends Record<Key, Key>>() =>
    async <By extends keyof Entity>(by: By, variables: readonly Entity[By][]) => {
        const entityMap = {} as { [key in Entity[By]]: Entity[] }

        const entities = [
            { a: 'hello', b: 1 },
            { a: 'world', b: 2 },
            { a: 'hello', b: 3 },
            { a: 'world', b: 4 },
        ] as unknown as Entity[];

        entities.forEach((e) => {
            if (!entityMap[e[by]]) {
                entityMap[e[by]] = []
            }
            entityMap[e[by]].push(e)
        })

        return variables.map((v) => entityMap[v]);
    };

const batchExampleEntitiesBy = batchEntitiesBy<ExampleEntity>()

const foo = batchExampleEntitiesBy("a", ["hello"])
```

I imagine `entities` is something that you will fetch from a server. If you use the parameterised version, you should probably inject the fetching behaviour to make sure it's aligned with the type you asserted. You should also check the type of your server response at runtime.

I would personally make this function synchronous and make it expect `entities` as an input.

```js
const entities = [
    { a: 'hello', b: 1 },
    { a: 'world', b: 2 },
    { a: 'hello', b: 3 },
    { a: 'world', b: 4 },
]

type Key = string | number | symbol;

const batchEntitiesBy = <
    Entity extends Record<Key, Key>,
    By extends keyof Entity
>(
    entities: Entity[],
    by: By,
    variables: readonly Entity[By][]
) => {
        const entityMap = {} as { [key in Entity[By]]: Entity[] }

        entities.forEach((e) => {
            if (!entityMap[e[by]]) {
                entityMap[e[by]] = []
            }
            entityMap[e[by]].push(e)
        })

        return variables.map((v) => entityMap[v]);
    };


const foo = batchEntitiesBy(entities, "a", ["hello"])
```

Comment: Unfortunately this approach does not work for me as it makes the assumption that Entity would `extends Record<key, key>`. The entities I will use will be objects I fetch from a database. Is there no way to define this function such that I could pass any class in? Or at least any class out of a set of pre defined classes?

Comment: In my third attempt, the only thing `batchEntitiesBy` cares about is that from a list of records of a certain shape, one can query a list of lists of records of the same shape, by some filtering criteria. It's a type safe generic function. If you don't expect a generic input, you should not use a generic. Generic parameters must be statically resolved when you pass an input to the function, but fetching `entities` from within involves asserting that it is of a known type, and throwing at runtime if it doesn't match the schema. It's a different process.

Comment: You can totally pass a class to that function, but that's a design discussion, not a typescript discussion. You should maybe update your question to reflect the design you are after in plain Javascript so that we can help you type it, but if you had gone through the trouble of implementing the fetch in your original code, I think you would have had a better insight to start with, because that tension between having a generic and fetching data - who is responsible for the type of the data - is very tangible.

Comment: I have now expanded my function in the original question a bit to explain better what my intentions are. When I try to implement the function the way you suggested it wont let me pass in <User> as the Entity...

Comment: to be clear the point where it doesnt work is whey I do `batchEntities<User, "addressId>` and if I dont put that it works but gives `Promise<Record<key,key>>` as a return type and I need the specific one... The error I get is `Type 'Address' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<k, k>'.
  Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'Address'.ts(2344)`

Comment: The types inferred in the examples of usage I gave in the answer are correct, but indeed If your implementation or usage differs, you will get different results. We need a minimal reproducible example. It may be possible to infer `Entity` from `entityClass`, or you could at least curry your function as I did in my version 2 to create a factory: you would for example do `const myClassBatchEntitiesBy = batchEntitiesBy<myEntity>(myClass)` to create a function which is dedicated to this class.

Comment: I would like to add, although it doesn't change the types issue, that your function would benefit from being broken down into smaller functions. You could leave `batchEntitiesBy ` as it is from my 3rd example, and call it from another function. This will allow to more easily test it as it is a pure generic synchronous function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248967/discussion-between-sev-and-geoffrey).

Comment: What would you need in addition for a minimal reproducible example beyond what I put above? If you have time to respond in chat that might be faster...